# Как реализовать условие на проверку даты?

Tags: python

Есть такой код:

```
 goose_date = parser.get_goose_date(resource_link)
                if goose_date is not None:
                # Выполнение методов
                else:
                    print('Гусь не нашел дату.')
```

То есть здесь стоит такое условие,если `goose_date` является `none` то ничего не происходит.Как к этому условию реализовать условие проверки на будущею дату.

Чтобы было как-то так.

```
if goose_date and future_date is not None:
```

То есть если будет такой случай когда `goose_date` возьмет будущею дату к примеру **30.10.2019 22:51**.Будет использоваться сценарий

```
                    else:
                        print('Гусь не нашел дату.')
```

Как реализовать условие на такую проверку?

Comment: сравнить goose_date  с текущей датой. Или о чем вопрос?

Comment: Если ее нет, то что тогда вы хотите проверять?

Comment: Я хочу чтобы в условие проверялось `goose_date` и будущая дата.Но т.к я ее нету я не могу понять,как мне ее проверять.

Comment: А на что вы хотите проверять будущую дату, которой к тому же нет???

Comment: На вопрос: "на что вы хотите проверять будущую дату?". На корректность то если есть будущая дата то это будет равносильно  `none`

Comment: Если будущая дата ГДЕ???

Comment: в каком гусе? в переменной ``goose_date``?

Comment: Так вам надо сравнивать не какую-то непонятную будущую дату, а ту дату, что содержится в ``goose_date`` с сейчас.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Реализовал таким способом:

```
if goose_date is not None:
                    if goose_date < time_now:
                    else:
                        print('Дата будущего!')
```

Comment: Да, примерно так.